# How to connect multiple database with testcontainers

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, mariadb, testcontainers

I have a app using an utility library where classes are defined as

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "event" ,  catalog = "GE_events")
public class Event{
...
}
```

while the app domain classes belong to the default catalog such as:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User{
...
}
```

Application services use both and this isn't a problem as far as the schema has already been created (either manually or with liquibase).

I wish to write an integration test using testcontainers

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE, 
  properties = {"spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create",
    "spring.jpa.show_sql=true",
    "javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source=data.sql",
    "spring.datasource.url= jdbc:tc:mariadb://localhost/test",
    "spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver"})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ServiceIntTest {
...
}
```

in this way the table `GE_events.event` is never created (and obviously the test crashes badly).

How can I achieve this result ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Liquibase to create the schema during test execution.

While you can still use the TC JDBC URL for this (I'd recommend using [daemon mode, `?TC_DAEMON=true`](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/#running-container-in-daemon-mode) in this case, to make sure no new database containers are created), most users tend to use the object API in this case, so creating a `MariaDBContainer` object and wire it up using Spring's [`DynamicPropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/DynamicPropertySource.html).